# How can I go about passing data from one php file to another via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, elgg

How can I go about passing data from one php file to another via JavaScript

data_from_here.php

```
<?php

    $guid = 99;

    require_js('javascript_file.js');
```

javascript_file.js

```
require(['elgg/Ajax'], Ajax => {

    var ajax = new Ajax();

    $('.glyphicon-zoom-in').click(function(event) {
        ajax.view('root/data_to_here', {
            data: {
                guid: 99 // Save the $guid from data_from_here.php in here
            },
        }).then(body => {
            $( '.full-image-view' ).html(body);
        })
    });
});
```

data_to_here.php

```
<?php

    echo $guid;
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but if you only need the information on the server, you should keep it there, for example in the session.

Comment: you can use GET, POST, Cookies.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that php is always execute before the page is delivered,
it permets you to write php code in the javascript.

for that include the javascript as a javascript_file.js.php
or write the javascript in a section of the php file.

data_from_here.php

```
$guid = 99;

require_once('javascript_file.js.php');
```

javascript_file.js.php

```
require(['elgg/Ajax'], Ajax => {

  var ajax = new Ajax();

  $('.glyphicon-zoom-in').click(function(event) {
    ajax.view('root/data_to_here', {
        data: {
```

Here we write the value in php

```
            guid: <?php echo $guid?> // Save the $guid from data_from_here.php in here
        },
    }).then(body => {
        $( '.full-image-view' ).html(body);
    })
  });
});
```

data_to_here.php

```
<?php

    echo $_GET['guid'];
?>
```