# How to dynamically pass data from PHP to JavaScript (In dynamically created HTML elements)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, requirejs

I have an array of entities populated from a database, each entity having its own **GUID**. I display them on a webpage **(HTML)** by looping through the entities array and placing each in a new dynamically created `div` wrapper.

```
<?php

$images = elgg_extract('entities', $vars, FALSE);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $img = elgg_view_entity_icon($image, 'small');
    $image_guid = $image -> getGUID();

    echo <<<HTML
    <div class="file-preview-frame">
        <div class="image-preview">{$img}</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn-default" data-guid={$image_guid}></button>
    </div>
    HTML;
}

elgg_require_js('js/inline_image_view');
```

**inline_image_view.js**

```
require(['elgg/Ajax'], Ajax => {

    var ajax = new Ajax();

    $('.btn-default').click(function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var recipient = button.data('guid') // Extract info from data-* attributes

        ajax.view('albums/inline_full_image_view', {
            data: {
                guid: recipient // querystring
            },
        }).then(body => {
            $( '.full-image-view' ).html(body);
        })
    });
});
```

How can I go about relating each button click to a specific image's GUID in inline_image_view.js in RequireJS? What is the best, or preffered way to go about this?

Thank you all in advance?

Comment: I answered you yesterday allready . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247952/how-can-i-go-about-passing-data-from-one-php-file-to-another-via-javascript/38249068#38249068 :-)

Comment: In this question, the elements are dynamically created in a loop. Each should maintain a unique GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Credits go to the [Elgg community](https://elgg.org/discussion/view/2516692/how-to-dynamically-pass-data-from-php-to-javascript-in-dynamically-created-html-elements), [Ismayil Khayredinov](https://elgg.org/profile/ihayredinov) in particular.

**albums/list.php**

```
<?php
$images = elgg_extract('entities', $vars);
echo elgg_view_entity_list($images, [
   'item_view' => 'albums/item_view',
   'no_results' => 'No images to show',
]);
?>
<div class="file-full-view-frame"></div>
```

**albums/item_view.php**

```
<?php
$image = elgg_extract('entity', $vars);
elgg_require_js('albums/item_view');

$img = elgg_view_entity_icon($image, 'small'); 
?>
<div class="file-preview-frame">
   <div class="image-preview"><?= $img ?></div>
   <?php
   echo elgg_view('input/button', [
      'class' => 'btn-default file-preview-show-full',
      'data-guid' => $image->guid,
   ], 'Show full'); 
   ?>
   </div>

</div>
```

**albums/item_view.js**

```
​define(function(require) {
  var Ajax = require('elgg/Ajax');
  var ajax = new Ajax();

  $(document).on('click', '.file-preview-show-full', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $elem = $(this);
     var guid = $elem.data('guid');

     ajax.view('albums/inline_full_image-view', {
         //data: $elem.data(),
         data: {guid: guid}
     })
.done(function (output, statusText, jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.AjaxData.status == -1) {
            elgg.register_error('Unable to load full image view');
            return;
        }
        $('.file-full-view-frame').html(output);
    });
  });
});
```